# Trying to check if users exists with a login system in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have ran this code on various PHP validators on the internet its says that these two functions (`mysql_query`, `mysql_result`) have been deprecated in the current version of PHP.

The following piece of code is not executing properly even though the username and password I type into the login form are the exact same as what is in the database/phpMyAdmin?

```
<?php
    function user_exists($username){

    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(user_Id) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
?>
```

Comment: **The following piece of code**. Where ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it there

Comment: Switch to **mysqli_*** and try the logic

Comment: this doesn't look safe to use at all

Comment: This `user_exists()` looks like it could work - are you sure you showed the code where the error is? There is no password here for example.

Comment: `mysql_result` returns "The contents of one cell from a MySQL result set on success, or FALSE on failure." [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) so if the contents are a string or any number other than 1 the check `==1` will always fail.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Don't think it will fail, after all `"1" == 1` is true in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

this should work :

```
$sqluserandpass = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sqluserandpass); 
$check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($check)){
   //User is existed
}else{
   //User is not existed
{
```

You should also avoid SQL injections by simply doing something like this :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

//execute
$stmt->execute();
```

Hope that was useful to you :)

Comment: This is useful, but still bad, because it doesn't explain how to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @Adder I'm not answering how to use PreparedStatement or how to avoid SQL injection, I'm aswering his question to solve his problem.